# Implement *ngFor in typescript

Tags: json, angular, loops, typescript

Good day, I am just wodering if it is possible to do the logic of *ngFor in the typescript? I want to loop the data from my JSON API in the typescript just like what *ngFor does in the HTML. Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: what do you mean? *ngFor is template syntax use in html

Comment: An JS or JSON array has `forEach` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: The *ngFor is a tipical thing of Angular. Do you use it?

Comment: @msanford the question is related to object´s key iteration, not arrays

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I don't understand your remark. (1) What leads you to that conclusion? The question is about JSON, which can be only an array (`JSON.parse("[]")` is valid). (2) the question I linked is _specifically about object iteration_.

Comment: @Patrick, what are you asking? Please, put your question clearly and put some codes. Try to specify what you have tried and what are you asking for?

Answer (score 1):

*ngFor is used on template to repeat over elements in array. If you want to loop over items in typescript i.e in **`TS`**, you can do this way

```
for(let item of this.result){

}
```

Comment: Do you srsly need to add an answer for this question, which shows 0 effort on research? Come on

Comment: @Jota.Toledo This comment, however, I agree with heartily. It's a half answer, at that.